# x is in S(closure) implies that there exist a sequence whose limit is x.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I prove such a statement that '' $x \in \overline{S}$ in $(X,d)$ implies that there exist a sequence whose limit is $x$.''  $(X,d)$ is a metric space and defn of $\overline{S}$ is the intersection of $C$ for which $C$ are closed and each $C$ contains $S$.?

Edit:
I tried to solve it by going from the definition of $\overline{S}$. Here what I argued : if $x \in \overline{S}$ ,then $\forall C: x \in C$ which are closed. If the $C$'s are closed then for every $\varepsilon$ there is a ball $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ such that intersection of the ball and the complement of $\overline{S}$ is not empty. Is this argument correct until here? and what direction should I go from here to get the sequence ?

Edit 2:
Thank you Nitrogen, if I had said $x$ is an accumulation point for $\overline{S}$ since for every $n$ we can find an element of $x_n$ around $B_{1/n}(x)$. By Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, there exist a sequence whose limit is that accumulation point, would it be correct?

If not, can you give the proof from where Nitrogen has left please by not using Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Edit 3: We have a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ and we want to show that this sequence converges to $x$. We wanna show  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d(x_n,x) = 0$
$d(x,x_n) < 1/n$ means limit of distance function goes to zero. Now proof is complete ? or not?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Providing the definitions you're working with already puts this question on the right track. The only thing this is missing is your attempts to solve it. What arguments did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Now you want to make a sequence appear. To do that, consider balls $B_n=B(x,\frac{1}{n})$ for every $n$. As you said, by definition $B_n\cap S\ne \varnothing$. In particular, there exists $x_n \in B_n\cap S$ for every $n$. Can you take it from here ?

Comment: if i had x is an accumulation point for S-closure since for every n we can find an element of Xn around b(x:1/n). by Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, there exist a sequence whose limit is that accumulation point , would it be correct?

Comment: I don't know what form of Bolzano-Weierstrass you have seen, but it is probably only valid in $\Bbb{R}^n$ so you cannot use it in an arbitrary metric space.

Comment: So how do you proceed from there ? hints are useful , but real analysis is a very new to me. i'm taking it for the first time and i'm majoring in economics. so you will be appreciated a lot if you help me solve by not using bolzano-weierstrass thm.

Comment: From my answer, you have now a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$. Try to show that this sequence converges to $x$.